# How to delete multiple folders from multiple Directories from command line

Tags: command-line, directory, cron, delete

I want to write a script for my Ubuntu users to delete multiple files from different directories at once. I what to run this on cron job so that it will do automatically. Eg. (I want to delete the files which are under Desktop, Downloads, Documents like the directories). I Don't want to delete the hidden files. only i want to delete from few directories.

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: What have you written so far, what kind of files are these and are they autogenerated?

Comment: You didn't specify any specific needs. So what's wrong about simple `rm`? (e.g. `rm -Ri ~/{Desktop,Downloads,Documents}/*`) (Change `-Ri` to `-Rf` if you really want to do this only)

Comment: @rovo `/home/*/{Desktop,Downloads,Documents}/*`  comes closer to his needs.  I would never do this from a cron job and always from /etc/profile. Plus I would also add in a IF matching usernames so you can log into the system with another user so the files are still there.

Comment: or `/home/{user1,user2,user3}/{Desktop,Downloads,Documents}/*`. True about the cronjob, seems not to be the right place.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen thanks for the reply, basically we have .doc, .docx, .gpg, like that files

Comment: @RoVo Thanks for the response, our user are in LDAP, and on a single ubuntu  system multiple users are using. Is there any way that i can delete the users fils from the Desktop, Downloads,Music directory by writing scripts.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the reply, can you please help me with the entire script.it would be really helpfull to me

Answer (score 0):

I’d use `find` with [`bash` Brace Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) as follows:

```
find /home/{user1,user2}/{Desktop,Downloads,Documents}/ -mindepth 1 ! -name ".*"
```

This finds every non-hidden (`! -name ".*"`) file and directory under the specified directories (`-mindepth 1`). If you want to delete the matching files, simply add the `-delete` option to the end of the command line.

If you need to use a shell without the brace expansion feature, just list the directories to be emptied:

```
find /home/user1/Desktop/ /home/user1/Downloads/ /home/user2/Desktop/ /home/user2/Documents/ -mindepth 1 ! -name ".*"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried the above command but its not working for me. am getting the error that No such file or Directory.

Here is my command - **find /home/users/{rajendra.acharya,rajender.naik}/{Desktop,Downloads,Documents}/ -mindepth 1 ! -name ".*" -delete**

All my users are authenticating through LDAP so I have given according to the USER locations

Comment: @Rajendra Did you use the correct path(s)? Are the files stored in e.g. `/home/users/rajendra.acharya/Documents`? You do use `bash`, do you?

Comment: Yes, I used the correct path. I didn't use bash.

Comment: @Rajendra Your question is tagged [tag:bash], you should [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1050675/edit) and remove this tag if it’s wrong. Which shell *do* you use? Regardless of the shell it should work without the brace expansion: `find /path/to/Desktop /path/to/Downloads …`

Comment: I removed the bash tag. Can you please help me with the full command. Means I want to delete the files and subdirectories, not the directories. It would be awesome if it possible to do this form multiple users at once.

Comment: Still i am getting the same error after typed the above command.

**find /home/user/rajendra.acharya/Desktop/ /home/user/rajendra.acharya/Downloads/ /home/user/rajendra.acharya/Documents/  -mindepth 1 ! -name ".*"**

I am getting the below error 
**find: `/home/user/rajendra.acharya/Desktop/': No such file or directory
find: `/home/user/rajendra.acharya/Downloads/': No such file or directory
find: `/home/user/rajendra.acharya/Documents/': No such file or directory**

Comment: @Rajendra Well, seems like there’s no such directory as `/home/user/rajendra.acharya/Desktop` etc. Double-check the paths, didn’t you say it’s `/home/users/…`?